# ModRewrite Domain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've done a little research into ModRewrite rules and conditions but have not been able to find a satisfactory set of rules/conds which achieve the effect I'm looking for.

Essentially, I have a directory on domain A (http://www.domaina.com/dir/) which I would like to redirect to a different directory on domain B (http://www.domainb.com/diff_dir/).

Note that I only want to apply the rewrite rule if the user is attempting to access /dir/ on domaina. If they are accessing a different directory or root I do not want to rewrite the URL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In domaina config:

```
#redirect everything under dir to the same location under domainb.com/diff_dir
RewriteRule ^/dir/(.*)$ http://www.domainb.com/diff_dir/$1 [r=301]

#redirect url http://www.domaina.com/dir to http://www.domainb.com/diff_dir
RewriteRule ^/dir(/)?$ http://www.domianb.com/diff_dir [r=301]
```

I didn't test this, but it should work.

Note:
If you're doing this in the root .htaccess file or in a specific directory config you'll want to drop the leading '/' or otherwise adjust the rule pattern. Something like `^dir(/)?$`.

Comment: You could put both rules into one line with something like  RewriteRule ^/dir(/?|/.*)$ http://www.domianb.com/diff_dir$1 [r=301]